# Elasticsearch: find documents with distinct values and then aggregate over them

Tags: elasticsearch

My index has a log-like structure: I insert a version of a document whenever an event occurs. For example, here are documents in the index:

```
{ "key": "a", subkey: 0 }
{ "key": "a", subkey: 0 }
{ "key": "a", subkey: 1 }
{ "key": "a", subkey: 1 }
{ "key": "b", subkey: 0 }
{ "key": "b", subkey: 0 }
{ "key": "b", subkey: 1 }
{ "key": "b", subkey: 1 }
```

I'm trying to construct a query in ElasticSearch which is basically equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), key, subkey
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key, subkey FROM t)
```

The answer to this query would obviously be

```
(1, a, 0)
(1, a, 1)
(1, b, 0)
(1, b, 1)
```

How would I replicate this query in Elasticsearch? I came up with the following:

```
GET test_index/test_type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggregations": {
    "count_aggr": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "concatenated_key"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`concatenated_key` is a concatenation of `key` and `subkey`. This query would create a bucket for each (key, subkey) combination and return a sample document from each bucket. However, I don't know how can I aggregate over the fields of `_source`.

Would appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the possibility to re-index the documents and to add **your own concatenated key** field, this is a way of doing it:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "key_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sub_key_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subkey",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will give you something like this:

```
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "a",
           "doc_count": 4,
           "sub_key_agg": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 0,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "b",
           "doc_count": 4,
           "sub_key_agg": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 0,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
```

where you have the key - `"key": "a"` - and then each combination with this key and the number of docs that match key=a and subkey=0 or key=a and subkey=1:

```
             "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 0,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 }
              ]
```

Same goes for the other key.

Comment: Hey Andrei, thanks for the answer! I can definitely add a concatenated key - note that I've mentioned its usage in the original question. Unfortunately this isn't exactly what I'm aiming for. I'm trying to count the distinct combinations of (key, sub-key). The query that you've provided breaks the count down into all combinations, but still provides the raw count (rather than the distinct count - which should be 1 in each bucket).

Comment: I'm not following. When will that count be different from 1, then?

Comment: Well, you can see in your queries that the doc_count for each bucket in sub_key_agg is 2.

Comment: I'm not talking about my query, I'm talking about your use case. To me your use case will always have 1 distinct combination, so that number will always be 1.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to re-explain myself. As you can see in the data sample I provided in the original post, I have two documents of each (key, sub-key) combination. I would like to count the _total_ number of distinct (key, sub-key) combinations (which in this case is 4). Does that make the purpose clearer?

Comment: Then use the concatenated key (note: you need to manually add this key to the documents) and use [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html) to count the distinct values.